# Const auto variable of "2d array" allows for modifiable value in const 2d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization, auto

So I'm using visual studio for this. I was fiddling around with creating arrays and realized that a const auto variable as an array allows for change in array value for some reason? Then I tried it with a const pointer array as well and it of course causes an error.

I initialized both the arrays to be set to all 0's. Yet if I change any value at a index in the const auto array it doesn't throw an error. I haven't tested this on any other frame works.

```cpp
int main()
{
    const int x = 5;
    const int y = 4;

    const auto arr = new int[x][y] (); //Sets arr to all 0's

    int a = 3; //variable to be inserted

    arr[0][0] = a; //Allows for change at index
    arr[3][2] = a; //Allows for change at index

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j)
      {
         cout << arr[i][j] << " "; //Prints arr
      }         
      cout << endl;
    }

    //Now on to pointer array
    const int *pt = new int[x * y] (); //Sets pt to all 0's

    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j)
      {
        pt[i * y + j] = a; //Obliviously Throws modifiable error 
        cout << pt[i * y + j] << " "; 
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
}
```

First array gets printed as such (const auto array):

3  0  0  0

0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0

0  0  3  0

0  0  0  0

Second array throws error as stated above.

Comment: There's no "const auto variable as an array" in your example. Your auto variable is a pointer. A const pointer. You need `const auto *arr` in order to make the first portion of your code to be similar to the second one.

Comment: Would it not be a const pointer variable to value then? Sorry I'm still new to c++.

Comment: It *is* a const pointer variable. But what it points to is not const. Which is why you can change it. Again, declare it as `const auto *arr`, and you will get a pointer to const, just like `const int *pt` in the second part of your code.

Comment: Ahh I see. Yep works as the 2nd one now. Thank you for clearing that!